# Executar um formulário (ou criar arquivo) só quando o programa for aberto pela primeira vez

Tags: c#

Quero saber se há como eu criar um formulário para ser aberto apenas na primeira vez que o programa for executado. Pois o formulário deverá criar um arquivo no sistema com o login na primeira vez que o programa for executado apenas, ele não poderá criar o arquivo sempre que o usuário abrir o programa pois caso o login tiver sido alterado ele será alterado novamente para o padrão.

Outra opção seria criar o arquivo na hora da instalação do programa mas não sei como fazer isso, já pesquisei bastante e não encontrei nada.

Não tem código pois não consegui fazer nada, só tentei colocar `File.Create("caminho");` na tela de splash, mas ele sempre cria um arquivo novo e substitui o antigo perdendo assim as informações gravadas nele.

Comment: Tentou criar uma variavel global booleana?

Comment: faça uma verificação! se com `File.Create("path")` funciona, faça algo assim `FileStream f = File.Open("path")`  e vc da a condição `If (f.exist) "exacuta A" else executa B"` crie uma função com `FileStream()` para verificar se o arquivo existe.

Comment: Não tinha tentado com variável global, resolvi tentar o método do Helbert primeiro, pois variável estavam redefinindo seu valor quando o programa fosse reiniciado (mas não usei global) .. Bom o método do Helbert funcionou, só tive que pesquiser, na verdade não é FIleStream nem File.Open.. Vou deixar a resposta embaixo..

Comment: Agora fica a dúvida de como criar formulários para serem executados apenas na primeira vez, mas com arquivo já da pra controlar melhor.. Acho que seria algo assim, na primeira execução, ele mostra o formulario e após o usuário clicar no botão de continuar por exemplo, apague o formulário para sempre ou mude o formulário de inicialização do programa

Comment: falha minha! é `FileInfo` eu utilizei uma vez para um problema similar, e tentei responder de cabeça, mais é isso ae… é possivel controlar isso se sua aplicação possui base de dados, ou vc pode utilizar os `setings` do project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, consegui aqui, ficou assim, logo embaixo do `InitializeComponent();` da tela de splash (para ele criar antes de abrir o primeiro formulário)

```
//Cria variavel com uma nova instância com informações de tal arquivo
FileInfo arq = new FileInfo("caminho-arquivo");

// se o arquivo não existir (por isso == false) ele é criado
if (arq.Exists == false)
{
    File.Create("caminho-arquivo");
}
// se não ele não faz nada, continua sua execução normal
else{}
```

Lembrando que deve-se importar a biblioteca IO (`using System.IO;`)